# Access blocked by cors in React even after using cors() in nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cors

Getting this very infamous error even after using **app.use(cors())** in my nodejs backend

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/visa/getOne/test' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested 
resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the 
resource with CORS disabled.
```

This is what I'm using in my nodejs **index.js:**

```
const express           = require('express');
const app               = express();
const mongoose          = require('mongoose');
const dotenv            = require('dotenv');
const bodyParser        = require('body-parser');
const engine            = require('./config/view.engine');
const router            = require('./routes/routes');
const session           = require('express-session');
const adminRouter       = require('./routes/admin.route');
const cors              = require('cors');
// Middlewares
//app.use(session({secret: 'mysupersecret', saveUninitialized: true, resave: true}));

app.use('/admin', adminRouter);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/', router);
app.use(cors());


// connect to db
dotenv.config();
mongoose.connect(
    process.env.DB_CONNECT,
    {
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useNewUrlParser: true
    },
    () => console.log("connected to db")
);

// use engine for views
engine(app);


app.get("/", (req, res) =>{
    res.send("This route wont return anything")
});

const PORT            = process.env.PORT || 5000
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log("server up and running"));
```

My route.js contains all the apis routes:

One of which is

`router.get('/api/v1/visa/getOne/:country_name', visaController.getOne);`

and inside getOne controller:

```
const getOne = async(req, res) => {

    try{
        Visa.find({country_name: req.params.country_name}, (err, result) => {
            if(err){
                res.status(400).send(err);
            }else{
                console.log(result);
                res.status(200);
                res.send({
                    error: "false",
                    data: result
                })
            }
        })
    }catch(err){
        res.status(400).send(err);
    } 
}
```

And finally my React fetch which is working fine with any other api:

```
fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/v1/visa/getOne/${searchValue}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data));
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try moving `app.use(cors());` above the route handlers so that is defined/registered in the stack application middleware prior to any other routes being defined:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/admin', adminRouter);
app.use('/', router);
```

Hopefully that helps!